# bash scripting in Unix - Sed. unknown Code

Tags: linux, unix, scripting

```
OLDEND = one 
NEWEND = two 
for FILE in *.$OLDEND 
  do 
    NEWNAME = `echo "$FILE" | sed -e "s/${OLDEND}\$/$NEWEND/"` 
    mv "$FILE" "$NEWNAME"
 done
```

I got this from a past exam paper and the questions just asked what it means. Can anyone help me out... I've an exam in 2 days and I'm trying to know all previous exams before I go in.

Comment: It means someone doesn't know how to assing a value to a variable in the shell.

Comment: could you elaborate on that for me please? 
Do you know what each line means individually by any chance?

Comment: I do. After reading your class materials, you should be able to know, too.

Comment: Reasked 24 hours later as [Unix operating system script](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23328608/unix-operating-system-script).  The main difference is that the revised version used `“` and `”` in lieu of `"`, which won't work as intended.

Answer (score 1):

1. find all files in current directory matching `<basename>.one`
2. with each file, rename to `<basename>.two`

However, as has been noted, it will fail. Should be `OLDEND=one`